# Displaying images in android?

Tags: android

I am working on student details application. I stored all the student details in sqlite database and I kept my sqlite file in assets folder. I need to display **the student photo also**. So for that I kept a **column in db and stored the image names of the students.** Now I am displaying the students names in a listview. When the student name is clicked it has to display all the details of that particular student along with the photo. How can I display a particular student photo? I kept the student photos in drawable folder.

My Code:

student.xml

```
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/yes" 
android:src="@drawable/photo"/>
```

Student.java

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.photo); 

ImageView Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yes); 

Image1.setImageBitmap(image );
```

Please help me regarding this....thanks in advance

Comment: you included images in sqlite file?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Are you getting an error or no image at all?
@vnshetty she has the images in the drawable folder(last line of question)

Comment: @ Antrromet its very difficult understand what she want.

Comment: Hi I am getting the image name from sqlite db...What I want is: For ex: the name of the img is aa.png then first I want to check that image in drawable folder and then I want to display that student corresponding image dynamically...

Comment: @RaagaSudha images in the drawable folder referenced as integer value. So you can do like i said in my answer no? any doubt?

Comment: @RaagaSudha You should be fatch the image from DB and should be android catch memory concept . its easy dude!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should store student photo id (drawable ID) in DB.

when user click on student name on List view get that student photo drawable ID from DB.

OR

store every student Photo drawable id in Listview li as Invisible get That ID when that Li clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/yes" 
android:src="@drawable/photo"/> 



Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
ImageView Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yes); 
Image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I kept the student photos in drawable folder.

Set Background Drawable to your Imageview.

```
 ImageView im =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
  im.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood You have all the student details in sqlite file and student name in drawable folder then you can do the following
1. give a unique id for student
2. and refer the same id for image name

then access the student detail from Sqlite file  and then display corresponding images. and you can make array of drawable resources for easy reference.

Answer (score 0):

fetch student image name from sqlite and after that just do this way

where StudentImageName is String

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("Your Package Name:drawable/" + StudentImageName, null, null); 
ImageView Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yes); 
Image1.setImageResource(resID);
```

and check image is present in drawable before set to imageview

either you can also try

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("Your Package Name:drawable/" + StudentImageName, null, null); 
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),resID); 
ImageView Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yes); 
Image1.setImageBitmap(image)
```

Comment: My db column data consists like this..

<div style="text-align: justify;"> Kiran Kumar <br />
<img height="150" width="150" src="/studentdetails/student1.png" alt="" /><br />&nbsp;</div>

From this at present I am displaying the student name. Now I need to display the image of that particular student. How can I get the image name from the above html 
code?

Comment: @RaagaSudha what studentdetails  contains and is it the folder in drawable  or other

Comment: all my images are in studentdetails folder. I kept that folder seperately in my project folder. But now I am unable to access the images from the studentdetails folder...Please help me

Comment: @RaagaSudha why not u put that folder in drawable

Comment: hi after google search I found that we cannot create a new folder in drawable folder..Isit possible to create a folder in drawable and access the images?

Comment: make folder name using drawble in res put ur images in that folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11223/discussion-between-khan-and-raagasudha)

Answer (score 0):

Include the photo when you insert student data in your database.
You can do this by converting the Bitmap into a byte array.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.photo); 
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

(Your image column should accept BLOB as field type)
Then whenever you want to display the image once again retrieve the byte array from the database then convert it to Bitmap so you can display it inside an ImageView

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray.length);

You can check this link for more info on
'How to insert image data to sqlite database in Android and how to retrieve it back'
https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html